# Many-to-Many relationship with GraphQL

Tags: graphql, many-to-many, graphql-js

Before I start I have already checked that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49903229/many-to-many-relationship-in-graphql)

Until now I was using plain `SDL` to define my schema in Graphql but recently I wanted to try with prototypes. I want to represent a many-to-many relationship between two nodes `User` and `Product` such that:

```
type User {
    id: ID!
    username: String!
    email: String!
    products: [Product]!
}

type Product {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    price: Float!
    users: [User]!
}
```

However, when I try to implement it with prototypes I get `Expected undefined to be a GraphQL type` error because one of the two object types has not been evaluated at the time of execution. At a moment in time, either User or Product will be undefined and I am not sure how to avoid that error. Can anyone help me?

```
const User = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'User',
    fields: {
        id: {type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)},
        username: {type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
        email: {type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
        products: {type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLList(Product))} // product has not been defined 
    }
})

const Product = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Product',
    fields: {
        id: {type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)},
        name: {type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
        price: {type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLFloat)},
        users: {type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLList(User))} 
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can lazy-initialize the fields passing functions instead of objects:

```js
const User = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'User',
    fields: () => ({
        id: {type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)},
        username: {type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
        email: {type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
        products: {type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLList(Product))}
    })
})

const Product = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Product',
    fields: () => ({
        id: {type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)},
        name: {type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
        price: {type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLFloat)},
        users: {type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLList(User))} 
    })
})
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I was trying to lazy load the whole object type but I didn't think for the fields. Thank you